# android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS is validating invalid emails

Tags: android, pattern-matching, email-validation

These are few emails which are not valid.

> email@domain.web
>   .email@domain.com

I have checked above emails in following websites, All of those returns invalid.
http://isemail.info/about
http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/Email_Address_Format_Validator.php.

Yet, `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` pattern validates both.

Is there a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: The first one certainly looks fine, [as `.web` is an unofficial TLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.web). The second one may be an issue.

Comment: Try this way hope this will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819142/how-should-i-validate-an-e-mail-address

Comment: The second email is invalid - Character . (dot, period, full stop) (ASCII: 46) provided that it is not the first or last character, and provided also that it does not appear consecutively (e.g. John..Doe@example.com is not allowed). Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both seems to be valid email addresses

> email@domain.web
>   .email@domain.com

since any email address contains three components

```
<username>@<mail-server>.<mail-servertype or server-location>
```

Here `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` validates all the three components using regex and also checks if all three components are placed properly. Some common confusing examples are:

1. `com@web123.com` is a valid mail address since `com` can be a user name and `web123` can be a web server's name.
2. `.maths.apple@com.in` is also a valid mail address since `.maths.apple` can be a user name and `com` can be a web server's name.

#### Invalid case:

`crick@.web.com` is invalid since a `.` cannot come before or after `@`. No mailing system will be able to recognize the username or mail-server name.

Comment: The local part ("user name" as you call it) cannot have a dot '.' at the start or the end of it unless it is in quotes.  If Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS is saying `.email@domain.com` is valid, it is violating RFC rules: "period (".") may also appear, but may not be used to start or end the
   local part..." - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3696

Comment: android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS also accepts stuff like **test@t.t** which is definitely not a valid email address. Top level domain with only 1 letter is not possible.

Comment: @DanielaVladimirova, One-letter TLDs are valid, they just don't exist yet. That could change at any time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411255/is-it-possible-to-have-one-single-character-top-level-domain-name

Answer (score 6):

Please check you are using right condition means you use same if condition. because some times we use vice-versa.
I know you are using the same thing but please check this method. I am sure it will be helpful for you.

/* returns true if the email is valid otherwise return false */

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public boolean checkForEmail(EditText edit, String editName) {
    String str = edit.getText().toString();
    if (android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(str).matches()) {
        return true;
    }
    toastMsg(_context.getString(R.string.please_enter_valid).toString()+" "+editName+ " "
            );
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way is to use the java Class InternetAddress instead of Android. Utils... or regex

Answer (score -1):

Use regex matching with this pattern below.

```
String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"


private Matcher matcher;
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);


public boolean validateEmail(final String hex) {
    matcher = pattern.matcher(hex);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

Hope this helps.