# Check constraint for Emails in an Oracle Database

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, constraints, email-validation

I've searched everywhere for a decent and logical `CHECK` constraint to validate that an email is in the right format. So far I've found really long and unnecessary expressions like:

```
create table t (
email varchar2(320) check (
regexp_like(email, '[[:alnum:]]+@[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]')
 )
);
```

and

```
create table stk_t (
email varchar2(320) check (
email LIKE '%@%.%' AND email NOT LIKE '@%' AND email NOT LIKE '%@%@%'
 )
);
```

Surely there is a simpler way?
I'm using Oracle 11g database and SQL Developer IDE.
This is what I have:

```
constraint Emails_Check check (Emails LIKE '%_@%_._%')
```

Can someone please let me know if this is the most efficient way of validating emails?

Comment: `really long and unnecessary expressions` most through email regexes are _much_ longer and more complicated than this.  Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) to get started thinking about this.

Comment: I don't see anything "unnecessary" in these expressions. Quite the opposite actually: the local part must not contain any '@'; a top level domain must consist of at least two letters; etc. You will end up with a more complex regexp_like. Maybe you'd prefer a trigger instead of a constraint, so you can use PL/SQL to check the string and raise an exception when it doesn't confirm to the rules for an email address.

Comment: Your check constraint considers '@@...' a valid email address which it obviously isn't.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "most efficient way" for validating emails - but some are better than others, some give too many false positives and others give too many false negatives.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, TLDs *can* have single letters, now :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411255/is-it-possible-to-have-one-single-character-top-level-domain-name

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp: Thanks for clarifying. So a@b.c would be invalid now, as c is currently no valid TLD, but may become valid in the future.

Comment: `[:alnum:]` means `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, however characters like `.-_` are also permitted - and fairly common.

Comment: Practically, of course, it's unlikely to be an issue in most cases. After all, any simple regex for email validation will have flaws no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
email varchar2(255) check (
email LIKE '%@%.%' AND email NOT LIKE '@%' AND email NOT LIKE '%@%@%'   )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before answering a question, always read the existing answers. This answer has already been provided. In fact, the OP looks for a more simple solution. Some guidelines for writing good answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(
  EMAIL VARCHAR2(30) CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE (EMAIL,'^[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9.]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$'))
)

Explanation of Regular Expression
^           #start of the line
  [_A-Za-z0-9-]+    #  must start with string in the bracket [ ], must contains one or more (+)
  (         #  start of group #1
    \\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+   #     follow by a dot "." and string in the bracket [ ], must contains one or more (+)
  )*            #  end of group #1, this group is optional (*)
    @           #     must contains a "@" symbol
     [A-Za-z0-9]+       #        follow by string in the bracket [ ], must contains one or more (+)
      (         #      start of group #2 - first level TLD checking
       \\.[A-Za-z0-9]+  #        follow by a dot "." and string in the bracket [ ], must contains one or more (+)
      )*        #      end of group #2, this group is optional (*)
      (         #      start of group #3 - second level TLD checking
       \\.[A-Za-z]{2,}  #        follow by a dot "." and string in the bracket [ ], with minimum length of 2
      )         #      end of group #3
$           #end of the line
```

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this answer while hunting for a simple solution on the internet:

```sql
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
ADD CONSTRAINT YourConstraintName CHECK(YourColumnName LIKE '%___@___%.__%')
```

All points to @bhanu_nz [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4754314a-a076-449c-ac62-e9d0c12ba717/beginner-question-check-constraint-for-email-address)